# Stacked bar plot, label bars with percentage values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to plot a table as a stacked bar plot and label the bars with the percentages. Here is an example:

```
data <- matrix(c(34, 66, 22, 78), ncol = 2)
data <- as.table(data)
colnames(data) <- c("shop1", "shop2")
rownames(data) <- c("prod1", "prod2")

library(reshape2)
data_m <- melt(data, varnames = c("Product", "Shop"), id.vars = "Product")

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_m, aes(x = Shop, y = value, fill = Product)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

I tried to add the labels with

```
geom_text(data = data_m, aes(x = Shop, y = value, 
                         label = paste0((value/100) * 100,"%")), size=4)
```

but this results in
[image]

EDIT: With JanLauGe's answer I get

[image]

Now, the percentages are wrongly assigned.

Another remark: what to do if the column sums of the table were not the same, say 91 and 107 instead of 100 as assumed in my above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead

```
geom_text(data = data_m, 
          aes(x = Shop, 
              y = value / max(value), 
              label = paste0(value/100,"%")), 
          size = 4)
```

The problem: label position is relative to the plot area (0 to 1, 1 = `max(value)`).

The solution: rescale value accordingly.

---

**EDIT**:
Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877645/geom-text-position-middle-on-a-bar-plot) post.

What you are looking for is this:

```
ggplot(data = data_m, 
       aes(x = Shop, 
           y = value, 
           fill = Product,
           cumulative = TRUE)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value/100,"%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: actually, try `value / 100` as well. But at the end of the day it depends on where exactly you would like the label. At the bottom, in the middle, or at the top of each chunk.

Comment: Ideally, the labels were at the middle of each chunk as in http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/01/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-4-stacked-bar-plots.html

Comment: duplicate, see my edit

Comment: How to modify your snippet in the case of different column sums?

Comment: the second snippet should still work exactly the same way

Comment: No, it does not, because the "100" in `paste0(value/100,"%")` has to be replaced by two different values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139233/discussion-between-joe-and-janlauge).

Comment: Your value / 100 only affects the labels, not their position of the labels. However, you can use something like value / sum(value) to get a different label value. This will give you percentage of total across all shops. If you want it grouped by shop, I recommend adding a separate total column to your data frame and using that to generate the label you would like.