# How to add percentage labels within a ggplot bar chart when using factors to fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [How to draw stacked bars in ggplot2 that show percentages based on group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group) . The data there is not purely factors and includes a "y =" in

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(year), y = amount, fill = type))
```

As far as I know, "y =" is not relevant to my example.

That said, my goal is to display the percentages for the factor used in fill within ggplot.  This is a bit different than other questions because I don't want to display the percentage for the x-variable—I want the percentages to be based on the fill variable, which will be a factor.  It's probably easiest to illustrate with mtcars.

```
df<-data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(mtcars$vs),fill=factor(mtcars$am))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

This gives us:
[image: ggplot of the above code]

What I want, however, is [image: something like this]

Comment: do you want the bars to be different heights based on number of observations? or just want to show the relative percentage in each bar?

Comment: @NateDay I want the bar height to be based on the x variable (in this case, the number of observations per factor in mtcars$vs).  The text for the percentages, however, should total 100% per bar and show the percent of each mtcars$am per factor in mtcars$vs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw stacked bars in ggplot2 that show percentages based on group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group)

Comment: @neilfws I've editted my question to clarify why I believe my situation is different.

Comment: I don't think your situation is different at all. You want percentages by group within stacked bars. It's the same problem as the duplicate question.

Comment: @neilfws I'll keep working at it.  Looks like the pre-processing requirement is where I'm getting hung up given that this is supposed to work within a larger function.

Comment: That error is probably because there is no `label` column in your data frame, as there is for the answer to the other question. There was another question only yesterday, very similar to yours, using the `mpg` data as an example; I'll try to find it. And there's this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065409/stacked-bar-plot-label-bars-with-percentage-values

Comment: @neilfws I was able to apply the technique in your link to mtcars and I believe this should work for my data as well.  The key thing I was missing is that I need to do more data preprocessing in converting my factors to values that ggplot can understand. Thanks!

Comment: Adding labels to stacked bars is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)